# Rectangle Collision Not Correct

Tags: c#, xna, collision-detection

[image: Collison]

As you can see on the top corner it says COL: False/True. This is if the player bounds and the tiles which are solids. The rectangles for the tiles and players are checked if they intercept each-other. Looks like its working right? Well nope. Look more closely.

[image: Not Working]
[image: Not working]

The **BOTTOM RIGHT** corner needs to be inside the tiles for it to count.

Now let's get to the code I used now that hopefully you understand the problem.

**Player Bounds (Rectangle)**

```
playerBounds.Width = 32;
playerBounds.Height = 64;
playerBounds.X = (int)this.position.X;
playerBounds.Y = (int)this.position.Y;
```

**Tile Bounds (Rectangle)**

```
newTile.bounds = new Rectangle(x * TILE_SIZE, y * TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE);
```

Now onto how it detects it:

```
for (int x = 0; x < Tilemap.MAP_WIDTH; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < Tilemap.MAP_HEIGHT; y++)
            {

                if (tm.tile[x, y].bounds.Intersects(playerBounds))
                {
                    if (tm.tile[x, y].getSolid())
                    {
                        Colliding = true;
                    } else
                    {
                        Colliding = false;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

**Move**

```
    public void Move(Vector2 pos)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < speed; i++)
        {

            position += pos;
        }

    }
```

I have used breakpoints at the collision detection loop. And the rectangle fully covers the character and the tiles.

Comment: You need colliding TRUE if any intersections occur, not just the last one checked.

Put colliding=false outside your loop.
Then do colliding = colliding || true; and remove colliding = false. 

You could also break out of the loop on the first collision detected, no need to see the rest!

Comment: Also this is in a update method.

Comment: Wait you might be right the break; fixed the top right corner.

Comment: @davidvanbrink Can you re-write my Colliding Function with said changes?

Comment: FIXED IT!
 Ill post answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        for (int x = 0; x < Tilemap.MAP_WIDTH; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < Tilemap.MAP_HEIGHT; y++)
            {

                if (tm.tile[x, y].bounds.Intersects(playerBounds))
                {
                    if (tm.tile[x, y].getSolid())
                    {
                        foundCols++;
                    } else
                    {

                    }
                }
            }

        }
        if (foundCols < 1)
        {
            Colliding = false;
            foundCols = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            Colliding = true;
            foundCols = 0;
        }
```

Answer by: David van brink.